# LaTeX export or convert into either R or Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, latex

Forgive me if this may be already asked. I am kind of new to all this. I wondered if there is a simple facility to have Matlab or R import or convert from LaTeX documents? This would be no different than how you can create a MuPAD script document and convert into Matlab M code. This would be through the Matlab Math Symbol toolbox. 
Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: you have (uncompiled) LaTeX documents that contain formatted R/Matlab code, and you want to import just the code into R/Matlab?

Answer (score 4):

No, converting general LaTeX equations into some sort of procedural programming language is most decidedly not possible.

LaTeX is a system for creating documents with structured text formatting and typesetting. It is not much different than writing individual letters and symbols onto a piece of paper yourself; there are no intrinsic semantics as to which symbols mean what. It doesn't know (or care) if the expression `x = y` is an assignment or a test for equality. Or if `\cdot` is a dot product or simple multiplication. All that really matters in the end is that the equations are readable and look good to a human eye. To convert this soup of symbols into a procedural programming language is quite impossible.

MuPAD, however, is a [computer algebra system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system). You tell it what is a function and what are variables. It has this knowledge.  As such, it is able to identify inputs and outputs and some sort of directional flow. It has a grammar to its equations: you must, for example, use `:=` to denote assignment. When converting to an m-file, MuPAD uses this additional information to determine which variables are scalar or vector, what is an assignment and what is a boolean test, what is input and what is output, etc.

This difference is obvious in usage of MuPAD vs LaTeX: one can rearrange and simplify your equations for you, the other cannot.